# java: get different parts of NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance() result

Tags: java, currency, number-formatting

In Java, with NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(), I can get a formatted string representing a price. e.g.

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.GERMANY);
System.out.println(nf.format(20.10)); // "20,10 €"
```

Is there an easy way to get the different part of this formatted string? i.e. something like

```
integerPart -> 20
decimalPart -> 10
currencySymbol -> €
decimalSeparator -> ,
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why you need to do this thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're really asking for two separate things:

1. `integerPart` and `decimalPart` belong to the *input* value. They can be calculated with some simple math:

   ```
   double input = 20.10;
   int integerPart = (int)input; // 20
   int decimalPart = (int)((input - integerPart) * 100); // 10
   ```
2. `currencySymbol` and `decimalSeparator` relate to the *output* value. They can be retrieved using the `DecimalFormatSymbols` class:

   ```
   DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY);
   String currencySymbol = symbols.getCurrencySymbol(); // €
   char decimalSeparator = symbols.getDecimalSeparator(); // ,
   ```

Comment: Thanks! But not completely agree with 1. Say if the input is 20.0163, the desired decimalPart would be "02". I know I can still get it by some processing, but since the NumberFormat has already done the job, I would like to just pick the result if possible.

Comment: @lznt Just use `(int)Math.round((input - integerPart) * 100)` or any other rounding method.

Comment: *since the NumberFormat has already done the job, I would like to just pick the result if possible.* The result is just a string. Sure, you could probably chop it up with regex if you really want. But that seems like a backwards way of doing things.